# Clojure - Joining Strings from separate lists

Tags: clojure

I have 3 lists `("Hello" "Hi" "Hey")` `("How's it" "What's" "Hey")` `("going?" "up?" "Hey!")`

How can I join the lists to get `Hello How's it going?` `Hi What's up?` `Hey Hey Hey!`

I know I can use `clojure.string/join " "` to join the strings in a single list but I want to join the first elements in each list, the second elements in each list, the third elements in each list ...

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map`.  If you pass in multiple collections, it will take an element from each collection and pass it to the fn:

```
(def a ["Hello" "Hi" "Hey"])
(def b ["How's it" "What's" "Hey"])
(def c ["going?" "up?" "Hey!"])

(map (fn [& args] (clojure.string/join " " args)) a b c)
```

This will result in:

```
("Hello How's it going?" "Hi What's up?" "Hey Hey Hey!")
```

But I'm sure with a little more thought a more elegant solution can be thought of :-).

Comment: The mapping function can also be written tersely for those who prefer that: `(map #(clojure.string/join " " %&) a b c)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map`:

```
(map (fn [& args] (join " " args)) '("Hello" "Hi" "Hey") '("How's it" "What's" "Hey") '("going?" "up?" "Hey!"))
```

Comment: (map vector ...) or (map list ...) if you are interested in creating a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate your lists into the whole one and them join it:

```
(def data '[("Hello" "Hi" "Hey") 
            ("How's it" "What's" "Hey") 
            ("going?" "up?" "Hey!")])

(clojure.string/join " " (apply concat data))

Hello Hi Hey How's it What's Hey going? up? Hey!
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired output. The goal is to join the first elements of each list, then the second, etc.